# Sum up the selected fields

Tags: text-processing, bc

I have a file with a numeric value in character positions 86 to 99. I want to sum up the entire amount present in the file, only for lines which contain `RS` at position 124-125.

I am trying to do like 
`amt=$(cat custbills.cmp| cut -c124-125|grep 'RS'|cut -c86-99|awk '{s+=$1 } END {print s }')` and when i do `echo $amt` it is showing Zero. what is wrong in this.

Fields in the file  from 86 to 111 like `0000000016.65201406051101` In this `16.65` is amount. I have 300 records in this file.

Sample data from 1 to 136 fields: `reportname                   123456-78956    customername                       0000000016.65201406051101          10RS    000000`

Comment: Can you post an example content of the file custbills.cmp?

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us an example of your input file and your desired output. How are the fields defined? Bu spaces? Tabs? Commas? Simple position? Something else?

Comment: @terdon I have mentioned in question the fields from 86 to 111 is like `0000000016.65201406051101` in this amount is `16.65`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. _Why_ is `16.65` fields 86 to 111? How are fields defined? If you mean columns, that looks like columns 9-13. Where does 86 come from? Please [edit] your question and give us an example of your input file and also show us your desired output.

Comment: @terdon♦ The fields shown to you at the column 4, and in this 86-99 are the fields of amount and from 100-111 shows the date. I cannot paste my data here sorry about that.

Comment: @Aravind then paste fake but similar data so we can know what you need. I'm afraid I don't understand your last comment at all. Again, how do you define a "column"? How do you define a "field"? We need to have an example of your input and your desired output. If it is sensitive information, just change it but keep the formatting identical.

Comment: @terdon `reportname                   123456-78956    customername                       0000000021.18201408231906          10RS    000000` i have given you the data from the field 1 to 136

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, please clarify if fields are defined by tabs or spaces and show us the output you would expect from this input.

Answer (score 2):

```
amt=$(
    grep -E '^.{123}RS' custbills.cmp |
    cut -c86-99 | 
    tr '\n' '+' | 
    bc
)
```

Or

```
amt=$(
    awk '
        substr($0,124,2) == "RS" {amt+=substr($0,86,14)} 
        END {print amt}
    ' custbills.cmp
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result is showing in exponential form. How can i change it to number form

Comment: which one did you try

Comment: I have tried second one. the total amount is about 9 digits

Answer (score 0):

you send to bc something like

```
12 34 56 22 56 98
```

with no operation string.

**edit** try

```
amt=$(cat custbills.cmp| cut -c86-99 |awk '{s+=$1 } END {print s }')
```

Comment: @ Archemar I have tried this, but it is giving zeros

Comment: @ Archemar i have tried this, it is giving sum. but i need to for record which contains `RS` which will be in the fields 124-125 i tried like this, but i am getting sum as zero. could you please help me `amt=$(cat custbills.cmp| cut -c124-125|grep 'RS'|cut -c86-99|awk '{s+=$1 } END {print s }')`

Comment: can you give a sample of both line (the one with RS, the one without) ?

Comment: every line contain either `RS` or `RT` at the field 124-125. I need  to find only for `RS` Ex: `99999960330RS`, `99999960830RT`

Comment: @Aravind, you have to put all your requirements in the question. Please edit the question accordingly.;